# sentiment analysis in python

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis, pos-tagger, senti-wordnet

I am extracting reviews from various website and storing them in a file and then classifying each sentence as positive or negative with the help of senti-wordnet ( which gives certain scores).I am using python 2.7. I don't know how it works for reviews stored in a file. Do anybody know the code in python for this ?

```
f1=open("foodP.txt","r")
word_features =[]
words = []

for line in f1:
    word_features.append(line)
    s=str(word_features)
    tokens=nltk.word_tokenize(s)    

for i,j in nltk.pos_tag(tokens):
    if j in ['VBN','VBP','VB','JJ', 'JJR', 'JJS', 'RB', 'RBR', 'RBS']:
        words.append(i)
print words
```

this code will give only adjective , adverbs and verbs i need. i want to classify these words as either positive or negative .

Comment: please post the code that you have tried. The message you have wrote is just what you want but what you have tried so far that is needed on this forum.

Comment: i have posted the code i used till now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need POS for sentiment analysis, at least it's not required. Prepare feature by using bag_of_words in X and "neg"/"pos" as Y. Then split into train/test sets and apply classification algorithm - NaiveBayes, MaxEnt, RandomForest, SVM.